# Android app closes after running few days (2days)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm am developing an app that suppose to run forever once the app is installed. I don't get any exceptions or crashes. Only error I'm able to find is as mentioned below

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 30752 (llay.myapp), pid 30752 (llay.myapp)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.663 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Amlogic/faraday/faraday:9/PPR1.180610.011/20191021:userdebug/test-keys'
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: pid: 30752, tid: 30752, name: llay.myapp  >>> com.foo.myapp <<<
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:662] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)weak global reference table dump:'
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  00007820  r2  00000006  r3  af663918
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     r4  00007820  r5  00007820  r6  bbdd51a4  r7  0000010c
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000b  r9  bbdd5211  r10 000008b4  r11 bbdd5210
2021-08-21 00:14:47.664 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     ip  00000041  sp  bbdd5190  lr  af5f20e5  pc  af5e9e72
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001ce72  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+62)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00356e7f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+798)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000071c7  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+502)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00236f6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::AddWeakGlobalRef(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+198)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 002b0d41  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewWeakGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+432)
2021-08-21 00:14:47.672 29579-29579/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 014c1b25  /system/app/webview/webview.apk (offset 0x780000)
```

Comment: You do realize that Android can just kill your app when it's low on memory etc?

Comment: By the looks there is an issue with the webview.apk system app.  At some point there are JNI calls in the app which contain `NewWeakGlobalRef` without using `DeleteGlobalRef` at some point in the future.  The system image might need updating, or tracking down the source code and seeing if there if a bug report for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a foreground service in android with a permanent notification.

Please do check my blog to get an idea about foreground service - https://medium.com/@kunal31/services-in-android-for-beginners-c3114810f430